# SD card limit says 8gb, Can I get a larger sd card to work?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, sd-card, hardware, ram, insufficient-memory

I'm thinking a buying a new phone, but it says the external sd card size limit is 8gb.  Can I do something to increase this to 16 or 32 gb.

Details:  phone: I-Mobile IQ 5.3

http://product.i-mobilephone.com/preview/53/1312

Android 4.2,  4gb rom, 1gb ram.

I don't want to root this right away.

The price is less then $200. unlocked.. Don't have $600.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to follow the max external SD card size limit. Otherwise, your phone might not be able to read the bigger-sized SD card.

Source: [Comments on using 64GB card on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-10-1/201713-64-gb-micro-sd-card.html)